When navigating back, the path of a NavigationStack is updated only after the transition - is it possible to react immediately?
When using a NavigationStack, the path-Binding is updated immediately when navigation happens via NavigationLink, but when using the back button, the path is only updated after the completion of the transition animation.
I want update another view that's next to the NavigationStack on iPad in parallel when navigation happens, but this always happens with a significant delay when navigation happens through the back button.
Is this possible? Is there a way to detect a change to the path immediately when it happens in all cases?
Code snippet to observe the update behavior of the path-Binding of a NavigationStack:
import SwiftUI

enum Location: String, CaseIterable, Hashable {
    case world, berlin, newYork, beijing
}

struct LocationView: View {
    let location: Location
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(location.rawValue)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var path: [Location] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                LocationView(location: path.last ?? .world)
                Button(
                    action: {
                        self.path = [.berlin]
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("Go to Berlin")
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                    }
                )
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                ZStack {
                    List(Location.allCases.filter { $0 != .world }, id: \.self) { loc in
                        NavigationLink(value: loc) {
                            Text(loc.rawValue)
                        }
                    }
                    .listStyle(.plain)
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Location.self) { loc in
                    LocationView(location: loc)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 400)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Side note: While investigating this, I found another glitch with the NavigationStack. If you change the path programmatically while the transition is running, at the end of the transition, this (newer) value will be overwritten. This can be reproduced with the example code above: Select a city in the list, go back, and while the transition is running, press the yellow "Go to Berlin" button.
Side note: In iOS 18, the behavior changed: the path binding is updated immediately.

As you have seen, the built-in back button just doesn't set the binding quickly enough. You will need to build your own back button.
// in the navigation destination view...
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
        Button {
            // send in a Binding<[Int]> so you have access to the navPath
            navPath.removeLast()
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.backward").bold()
            Text("Back")
        }
    }
}

In addition, the environment value isPresented is immediately set to false when the back button is pressed, so you can also detect this in the destination view.
struct DestinationView: View {
    @Environment(\.isPresented) var presented
    
    var body: some View {
        SomeViewHere()
            .onChange(of: presented) { _, newValue in
                if !newValue { /* do something */ }
            }
    }
}


For iOS 18, the behavior changed and the path binding is updated immediately.
For iOS 17, one can work around the issue: onAppear of the destination view you're going back to is called immediately when the back button is tapped.
Code snippet to observe this:
@Observable class ExampleModel {
    var navPath: [Int] = [] {
        didSet {
            print("navPath changed: ", navPath)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var model = ExampleModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $model.navPath) {
            ListExampleView()
                .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { value in
                    Text(String(value))
                        .onAppear {
                            print("Detail onAppear")
                        }
                        .onDisappear {
                            print("Detail onDisappear")
                        }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ListExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< 30) { item in
                NavigationLink(value: item) {
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("ListExampleView on onAppear")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Example")
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}

(So at least it's possible to detect the change at all / build a workaround; but I am still looking for a consistent way to read an immediately up-to-date nav path before the transition animation is completed).
